# Changing the display of mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to ask how to change the display of data from one mysql table to another.

This is the table that I am getting (i select few rows only):

```
TagName, DateTime, Value
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0019.Zone1_current', '2022-06-03 15:32:38.2570000', '0.15'
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0019.Zone1_Voltage', '2022-06-03 14:57:26.6450000', '3.66'
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0019.Zone1B_Current', '2022-06-03 14:57:26.8950000', '0.12'
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0019.Zone1B_Voltage', '2022-06-03 15:51:53.3120000', '1.35'
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0019.PV_HUMIDITY', '2022-06-03 15:42:37.5800000', '85.05'
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0019.PV_Temp', '2022-06-03 15:39:23.2990000', '-64.3'
```

But 'SGHAST' can be 'SGTC' or 'SGTHB' or 'SGTHS' or 'SGBAKE' or 'SGREFLOW' or 'SGSOAK'

and

This is how i want to do the table for mysql (now only showing 1 line):

```
Chamber, Temperature, Humidity, Voltage, Current
'SGHAST.0019', '-64.3', '85.05', 'Zone 1: 3.66, Zone 1B: 1.35','Zone 1: 0.15, Zone 1B: 0.12'
```

Is it possible to do so? The end goal here is to connect the database table to a webpage to show the table at the webpage using php and javascript. Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Self join the table.

Comment: Do u mind showing an example of the code? bc i am still quite new to mysql sorry

Comment: @BoristheSpider do u have the code especially for this set of table?